# Set up 2 factor authentication for Gmail but NOT Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, multi-factor-auth

I'm using YouCanBook.me and enabling 2FA seems to have broken it.

Is there a way to set up 2 factor authentication for Gmail but *not* for my Google Calendar?

Comment: I use youcanbook.me *and* 2FA on my Google account, with no problems. (I had 2FA before I signed up for YCBM).

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not, no. 2-step verification is for your Google Account, not for any particular app.

However, you should be able to create an app-specific password. These are special passwords for apps that don't support 2-step verification that you want to give access to your account.

1. Go to the [2-step verification](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#asps) page in your MyAccounts.
2. On the "App-specific passwords" tab, click "Manage application-specific passwords"
3. Select "Other (Custom name)" and give it a name, such as "YouCanBook.me"
4. Click "Generate"
5. You'll get a 16-character password that, along with your Google Account username, will allow access to your account. Use that from YouCanBook.me to connect.

Notes:

- Don't dismiss the window until you've got the password. Google will never show it to you again, so if you don't get it you'll need to revoke the password and re-do the process.
- Don't use the same app-specific password with any other apps. This way when you decide to leave YouCanBook.me (or you decide that they've been hacked) you can revoke that password without affecting any other apps you've set up that way.

More information at [Google Support - Sign in using App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)